# is it possible to enumerate the public static strings in an object?

Tags: c#

In this code they've used this construction instead of an enum:

a public class with all public static strings.

Is it possible to enumerate over static strings in a class?

Comment: should be possible using reflection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will enumerate string values of public static fields in the class `MyClass`:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static;
var query = typeof(MyClass)
        .GetFields(flags)
        .Where(fieldInfo => fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(string))
        .Select(fieldInfo => fieldInfo.GetValue(null));
foreach (var value in query) {
    // ...
}
```

For public static properties it is almost the same:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static;
var query = typeof(MyClass)
        .GetProperties(flags)
        .Where(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        .Select(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null));
foreach (var value in query) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection:
`yourobject.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public)` will return all the static field of your class.

Comment: Then check the field type == typeof(string)

Answer (score 0):

I started writing this before the other answers so might as well post my answer too.

```
public class PublicStringIteration
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyStrings myStrings = new MyStrings();
        foreach (string value in myStrings.GetStaticFieldValues())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }

}

public class MyStrings
{
    public static string String1 = "String1 Value";
    public static string String2 = "String2 Value";
    public static string String3 = "String3 Value";
}

public static class MyStringsExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetStaticFieldValues(this MyStrings myStrings)
    {
        Type myClassType = typeof(MyStrings);
        foreach (MemberInfo info in myClassType.GetMembers())
        {
            if (info.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
            {
                yield return myClassType.GetField(info.Name).GetValue(info).ToString();
            }
        }
    }

}
```